# Why isn't tcpdump rotating save files?

Tags: pcap, tcpdump

I'm trying to get tcpdump to rotate through a number of pcap files based on both file size and time using the following command:

```
tcpdump -i lo -G 60 -W 5 -C 1 -w /var/tmp/trace
```

I expected it to rotate through 5 different log files (named trace0, trace1, trace2 etc.) when they either reach a maxmimum size of 1M (from the -C option) or after 60 seconds have elapsed (from the -G option). Instead only trace0 is created and it gets overwritten once the 60 seconds have elapsed.

Based on the man page's explanation of the -G argument I thought that, because I am also using -C, the files would be saved with the format 'file<count>':

> -G rotate_seconds
>   If specified, rotates the dump file specified with the -w option every rotate_seconds seconds. Savefiles will have the name specified by -w which should include a time format as defined by strftime(3). If no time format is specified, each new file will overwrite the previous.
>   If used in conjunction with the -C option, filenames will take the form of `file<count>'.

If I omit the -G option then multiple files will be created as expected, but in that case they only rotate based on file size and not time.

Is there something I'm missing that would explain why I'm only getting trace0, and not the other four? My tcpdump version is 4.9.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If no time format is specified, each new file will overwrite the previous.

You'll have to add something like %H:%M:%S to the end of your file name to prevent the override from happening. To control the amount of files, you can workaround by hooking into post-rotate command

Cleanup script:

```
echo 'ls -tp trace*| tail -n +6 | xargs -I{} sh -c "echo \"Removing {}\"; rm {}"' > cleanup.sh && chmod a+x cleanup.sh
```

Tcpdump command

```
sudo tcpdump -i lo0 -G 1 -W 5 -C 1 -w trace%H:%M:%S -z ./cleanup.sh
```

Example output:

```
tcpdump: listening on lo0, link-type NULL (BSD loopback), capture size 262144 bytes
Removing trace11:45:580
Removing trace11:45:570
Removing trace11:45:590
Removing trace11:46:000
Removing trace11:46:010
```

Resulting files

```
ls -la trace*
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff   24 Jul  5 11:48 trace11:48:250
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff  894 Jul  5 11:48 trace11:48:270
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff  894 Jul  5 11:48 trace11:48:280
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff  894 Jul  5 11:48 trace11:48:290
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff  894 Jul  5 11:48 trace11:48:300
```